# PHP class private property and method

Tags: php, oop, private, private-members, private-methods

Noticed something about PHP's classes and I don't know if it's a bug or why it works, this is the code:

```
<?php
class A {
    private $prop = 'value';

    public function fun()
    {
        $obj = new A;
        $obj->echoProp();
    }

    private function echoProp()
    {
        echo 'Prop has value: '.$this->prop;
    }
}

$obj = new A;
$obj->fun();
```

And the result isn't an error as I was expecting since I'm calling a private method (tested on PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 with Suhosin-Patch). The result is "Prop has value: value"

Comment: How would you expect private methods to be called instead if not from public methods?

Comment: To be specific, you're NOT calling a private method, you're calling a public method that calls the private method. The public method has access to the private method, but calling `$obj->echoProp();` will fail because in that case you're calling the private method.

If your expectation was true, nothing would be able to call a private method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the php documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-other-objects it says:

> Visibility from other objects
>
> Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and
>   protected members even though they are not the same instances. This is
>   because the implementation specific details are already known when
>   inside those objects.

So this isn't a bug but a wanted feature of php.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're in the class, you can call your class' private methods on any instance.